# javascript as response text

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have an Ajax function which will retrieve some RSS feed script from server. I put this responsetext in a div using:

```
$("#divId").html(responsetext);
```

I want to execute the script inside the response. Currently, the RSS feeds not showing in the div. Is there any way to do that ? thanks..

```
responsetext
-------------  -

<div class="last-updated"  style="display: block" id="p-lastUpdated">Last Updated:16 Jun 2010 10:32 AM</div> 

<div id="digg-widget-1276598296115">

<a href="http://digg.com/search?s=timesofindia.indiatimes.com">See more timesofindia.indiatimes.com stories.</a>

</div>

<script type="text/javascript">

(function() { var s, s1, diggWidget = {id: "digg-widget-1276598296115", layout: 1, colors: {hdrBg: "#1b5790", hdrTxt: "#b3daff", tabBg: "#4684be", tabTxt: "#b3daff", tabOnTxt: "#d41717", bdyBg: "#fff", stryBrdr: "#ddd", lnk: "#105cb6", descTxt: "#999999", subHd: "#999999"}, title: "RSS Times of india", width: 480,height: 300, requests: [{t: "timesofindia.indiatimes.com", p: {count: "10", sort: "promote_date-desc", method: "story.getPopular", domain: "timesofindia.indiatimes.com"}}], hide: {footer: true, header: true}, target: "_blank", descriptions: "show", rounded: true}; if (window.DiggWidget) { if (typeof DiggWidget == 'function') { new DiggWidget(diggWidget); } else { DiggWidget.push(diggWidget); } } else { DiggWidget = [diggWidget]; s = document.createElement('SCRIPT'); s.type = 'text/javascript'; s.async = true; s.src = 'http://widgets.digg.com/widgets.js'; s1 = document.getElementsByTagName('SCRIPT')[0]; s1.parentNode.insertBefore(s, s1); } })();

</script>
```

Comment: Is the RSS feed you're grabbing on a different domain?

Comment: Hi Nick, It is from same domain

Comment: You have to be *very* sure the script inside the response doesn't contain malicious code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My answer from [How To Call Javascript In Ajax Response? IE: Close a form div upon success](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2991295/how-to-call-javascript-in-ajax-response-ie-close-a-form-div-upon-success/2991489#2991489)

```
// response is the data returned from the server
var response = "html\<script type=\"text/javascript\">alert(\"foo\");<\/script>html";
var reScript = /\<script.*?>(.*)<\/script>/mg;
response = response.replace(reScript, function(m,m1) {
    eval(m1); //will run alert("foo");
    return "";
});
alert(response); // will alert "htmlhtml"
```

Comment: Hi Sean, thank you very much for the answer. But this is not working in my case. I have updated the question with the response text.

Answer (score 0):

Is the response mixed HTML and JavaScript or just pure javascript?

If it's pure javascript you can always use the `eval("alert('Test');")` function which executes the code sent.

Comment: It is mixed HTML and JavaScript... :(